# What does it take to design a Flipboard-like iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm learning iOS development and want to build an interactive magazine app like Flipboard, which doesn't seem too complex. I know I can build something comperable with UIWebView but I'd rather learn how to build an interactive native app.

Can anyone tell me what high level client-side iOS Frameworks are involved so I can focus on learning them? (Animation, Navigation...) Any articles or code samples would be even better.

Thanks

Comment: I think this might be too general a question to be answered effectively as-is. Perhaps you should try to prototype a single-page view and see where you start seeing some gaps between your vision and what is straightforward to achieve.

Comment: What iOS frameworks are used to achieve the transition animations?

Comment: Core animation.  Also a sample application can be found on [github](https://github.com/Reefaq/FlipView).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep it simple, Apple's built in UIPageViewController will get you most of the way. There are a number of open source FlipBoard-style transition libraries. Two that have come through my feeds before (although I haven't used either in anger) are:

https://github.com/Reefaq/FlipView

https://github.com/Dillion/iOS-Flip-Transform

Comment: Word to the wise, UIPageViewController is a bloated mess.